# ConstraintViolationException Duplicate entry when using @EmbeddedId

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i have the following entities:

**1- ADDRESS**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class Address implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private AddressPK id = new AddressPK();

               @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Insurance_Detail insuranceDetail;

}
```

**2- ADDRESSPK**

```
@Embeddable
public class AddressPK implements Serializable
{
    // default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(unique = false, nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String customer_EmailAddress;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int address_Id;

}
```

3- **Insurance_Detail**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Insurance_Detail")
public class Insurance_Detail implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private AddressPK id;

    @OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "customer_EmailAddress", referencedColumnName = "customer_EmailAddress", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "address_Id", referencedColumnName = "address_Id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })



}
```

**4- Persisting the address object** is as follows:

```
Address address= new Address(data1,data2);

address.getId().setCustomer_EmailAddress(
                    currentCustomer.getEmailAddress());

entityManager.persist(address);
```

**5- Persisting the insurance details** object is as follows:

```
Insurance_Detail insuranceDetail = new Insurance_Detail(address.getId(), data3,data4);
entityManager.persist(insuranceDetail);
```

and it's saved correctly with no problems.

**ISSUE:** when trying to **persist** the **Insurance_Detail** object, in first insertion for an insurance, it's persisted successfully, but in second insertion for another insurance i am getting the following exception.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'test@msn.com' for key 'customer_EmailAddress'; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'test@msn.com' for key 'customer_EmailAddress'
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

please advise how to fix this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISSUE was in database side, i was having `UNIQUE INDEX` on the `customer_EmailAddress` and also the primary key order has to be equivalent to join columns

```
PRIMARY KEY (`Customer_EmailAddress`, `Address_Id`)
```